# gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy

Tags: google-signin, google-authentication

I'm trying to add a Google Sign In Authentication system to my app, but I keep getting a strange error that I haven't seen anyone get. I'm using EXACTLY the [google example code](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/).

I thought it could be some mistake when loading the api, so I checked the async loading and everything seems to be loading properly, but I keep getting this error in the console:

> gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy

I searched everywhere for people with the same problem, but I could not find anything similar.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I tried to create a page with ONLY the code of the tutorial, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 105):

Well, turns out I was trying to test the API by directly acessing my files locally (index.html). The Google Sign In API only works in a running web server. I started a simple node.js server, ran my app trhough this server, and everthing worked just fine.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Now if I just knew how to start a simple node.js server :)

Comment: I used to think this was complicated but it isn't. install python. cd to the directory of your html file then run "python -m http.server 8000"

Comment: Thanks this worked after running it on a node server.

Comment: I got same error on chrome extension, web is working fine. Please tell me how to solved this issue.

Comment: Will this work on Xampp? Or limited just for NodeJs Server

Answer (score 10):

As already answered by KoJoVe, you need to run inside a web server. If you are using Python 2.7 you might use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and then use localhost:8000 on your browser

Answer (score 4):

I've been trying to get a chrome extension to work for a very long time, and I recently decided to click into the error. The reason is because the google platform script checks `window.location.protocol` (which isn't https for chrome extension) and throws the error 'invalid cookie policy'.

My theory as to why Google won't fix this:

1. They want to drive people into using paid OAuth2 endpoints
2. They want to know who received the tokens, if possible (via certificate authorities)

Comment: Have you figured it out how to implement auth2 in chrome-extension because i'm strugling with this too

Comment: @NaveenKashyap I gave up, and there's a difference between OAuth and OpenID which is what I wanted to use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556339/can-chrome-extensions-steal-oauth-tokens-from-redirect-uri

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem using [react-google-login](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login) in a create-react-app, and I found that I was accessing the page with `http://[::1]:3000/sign_in` instead of `localhost`.

I think google does not like `127.0.0.1` or `::1` since we expose the IP directly or something

When I change to `localhost:3000` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case with python 3:

open python terminal and write the following code:

```
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as handler
import socketserver as socket
httpd = socket.TCPServer(("",8000),handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```