# Error while adding google sign-in to website

Tags: google-signin

I was trying to add google sign-in to my website, when I came across an odd error preventing google sign-in from working.

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:158 Uncaught gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy
```

I put all of my info in the meta element of the website and configured it to run on localhost:8080, but, strangely it is not working.

If anyone has any insight on this issue could you please notify me on why this error is occuring, and what could be causing it.

Comment: Maybe this thread could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896597/google-sign-in-auth-invalid-cookie-policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was dealing with the same problem finally fixed with:

- Put the file on a web server.
- The scripts should be in the header section of the page (I know! )