# google api authorization error "invalid cookie policy"

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I tried to use Google api but this method

```
gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive '],
        'immediate': true
    },
    handleAuthResult);
```

give me an error object

> {
>       message:
>   "Invalid cookiePolicy"
>   stack
>   :
>   "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy
>       at new uO ([https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:351:25](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:351:25))
>       at Object.*.tY ([https://apis.google.com/](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:365:246)*/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:365:246)
>         at Nm ([https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:368:462](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:368:462))
>       at Object.*.jH ([https://apis.google.com/](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:385:55)*/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:385:55)
>       at [https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:641:58](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:641:58)
>       at new *.C ([https://apis.google.com/](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:82:299)*/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:82:299)
>       at Object.*.hx [as authorize] ([https://apis.google.com/](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:641:34)*/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.it.cWuXt0TFtAc.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=QQE/rs=AGLTcCNBVmWsKdwnYSZ6gdBgYWDV40Vbng/cb=gapi.loaded_0:641:34)
>       at onAuthApiLoad}

How can I fix it? It should return Oauthtoken, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896597/gapi-auth2-externallyvisibleerror-invalid-cookiepolicy)

Answer (score 2):

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896597) you need a web server to execute Goolge Pickers. Start your webserver first  either using Python's:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

or for python 3.X

```
python -m http.server 8080
```

or [NodeJS webserver](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp).