# Chrome extension gmail API cookiePolicy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api

I'm building a chrome extension that will read the user's emails and check them for typos. However, when trying to authenticate the user in my background.js I'm running into this error:

> uO {message: "Invalid cookiePolicy", stack:
>   "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookieP… at handleResponse
>   (extensions::sendRequest:67:7)"}

Here is how I'm trying to authenticate them:

**background.js**

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=callbackFunction";
head.appendChild(script);

chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, authorize);

function authorize(token) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: '800382879116-k3luktdc1lmb1e1fml8i8u.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        immediate: true,
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
    },
    function(result){
        console.log(result);
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', callback);
    });
}
```

**background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src='scripts/background.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
  {
    "name": "Gmail Typo Analyzer",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Gmail Typo Analyzer",
    "permissions": [
      "identity",
      "storage"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
    "oauth2": {
      "client_id": "82879116-k3luktdc1li8u.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "scopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
      ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": "images/Icon_16.png"
    },
    "background": {
      "page": "background.html",
      "persistent": false
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/Icon_16.png",
      "32": "images/Icon_32.png",
      "48": "images/Icon_48.png",
      "128": "images/Icon_128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "key": "c0Kn5f+t92r4P8lmmoDlKtQ6X9Q42UfFtkkiSRBAVMPHnIHqOQvYC67VczJefSNTGpUYa8+wQDFoFj/clH9SfR+BvOGgI6BUVKBNGGoFS"
  }
```

I'm super lost right now as their doesn't seem to be a definitive guide on achieving what I'm trying to do anywhere. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I want to refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow) where the OP solved the problem about CORS and suggested to use this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).

Comment: Try changing the permission to `"https://apis.google.com/"` - you can't specify a path there.

Comment: Have you seen [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896597/gapi-auth2-externallyvisibleerror-invalid-cookiepolicy)?

Comment: Both `callback` and `callbackFunction` are undefined in your code. You never check nor use the `token`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I saw that. But I want my chrome extension to run on the user's browser, not on some webserver I host.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't post your `manifest.json` file, where you would set the [`oauth2` credentials](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#update_manifest), so I  would try something like:

**manifest.json**

```
...
"oauth2" : "client_id": "800382879116-k3luktdc1lmb1e1fml8i8u.apps.googleusercontent.com",
           "scopes": [
               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
           ]
...
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, authorize);

function authorize(token) {
    if (token) {
         //user has given authorization, use token for requests.
         //...
    } else {
         //no authorization received.
         console.log('No authorization. Error: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError);
    }
};
```

And you don't need to load Google API client, you can access [Gmail's Restful API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) with `XMLHttpRequest`s or [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Answer (score 0):

I used to get that cookie error too, but for Chrome extensions I only know how to load them from unpacked in the Extensions tab. So using gapi directly never worked for me.

As Ivan mentioned, Chrome extensions have this support "built-in" by setting the "oauth2" section in the manifest. Then you can call the APIs directly with Ajax like Ivan's example.

To build on Ivan's example, this is my working code to get a list of contacts. I haven't read from the XHR object yet, but Fiddler confirms that the data is coming back fine without any cookie or CORS errors. Of course make sure you enable these APIs in console.developers.google.com.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, authorize);

function authorize(token) {
    if (token) {
        console.log(token);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET',
            "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?personFields=names");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
            'Bearer ' + token);
        xhr.send();

        //user has given authorization, use token for requests.
        //...
    } else {
        console.log('No authorization. Error: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError);
    }
};
```