# Using gapi in chrome extension background script, Invalid cookiePolicy

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to build a chrome extension which should highlight certain things on the page if they appear in a user's google sheet.

When trying to initialize gapi object in the background script, I'm getting `gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy`. When searching or this error i didn't really find a solution for my case (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896597/gapi-auth2-externallyvisibleerror-invalid-cookiepolicy)).

I wanted to load the sheet into memory just once using gapi in the background script, and not do this in every tab (content script).

I also found several posts which mentioned that gapi and OAuth2 don't work well in chrome extensions, can anyone please explain? Is this a general no-no?

Comment: I am also looking for the same, my extension is also having the same issue

Comment: @Yossi did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @iulian Not really, i decided not yo use gapi but just to directly invoke REST API

Comment: @YossiVainshtein thanks for your answer! I'll use the [identity.launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) browser API to launch google auth popup to get auth token

Comment: are you solved this issue??